# Centering button with fixed width breaks NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have an interesting problem. My app is entirely managed through code instead of storyboards. I have a UIViewController which is presented programmatically. It creates a button and constraints for it.

This is what the controller code looks like.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button =  UIButton()
        button.layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        return button
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[button]-100-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["button": button]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[button(50)]-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["button": button]))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
}
```

It throws this error.

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000288bb60 UIButton:0x7fa1ab422680.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000032da760'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading NSSpace(0)   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000288bb10 UIButton:0x7fa1ab422680.width == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000288d7c0 UILayoutGuide:0x6000032da760'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == UIButton:0x7fa1ab422680.trailing NSSpace(0)   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028fe990 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fa1ab4224a0.width == 375   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000288fe30 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(16)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000032da760'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fa1ab4224a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000288d180 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000032da760'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(16)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fa1ab4224a0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000288d7c0 UILayoutGuide:0x6000032da760'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == UIButton:0x7fa1ab422680.trailing NSSpace(0)   (active)>
```

My aim here is pretty simple. I want the button to be 100 pixels above the bottom, to be centered horizontally, and to have a fixed width and height.

This is how the controller is being instantiated. It exists inside of a

```
        let nav2 = UINavigationController()
        let create = CreateViewController()
        nav2.viewControllers = [create]
        nav2.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        ...
        let tabs = UITabBarController()
        tabs.viewControllers = [..., nav2, ...]

        tabs.delegate = self
```

Any help in understanding why these constraints are being violated would be greatly appreciated! If any part of the question is unclear, just let me know.

FYI the resulting view looks like this:

[image: the button is not centered here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering an element with Visual Format Language is difficult.

You can ***easily*** do it using `.centerXAnchor`:

```
class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button =  UIButton()
        // next line is not needed
//      button.layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        return button
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func setupConstraints() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // button width of 50
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),

            // button height of 50
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),

            // bottom of button 100-pts from bottom of view
            // note: contant is negative!
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),

            // center the button horizontally
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),

            ])

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try following way to add constraints which is more swifty and cleaner

```
func setupConstraints() {
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
                                           attribute: .top,
                                           relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: self.view,
                                           attribute: .top,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 100)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
                                              attribute: .left,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: self.view,
                                              attribute: .left,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 100)
    self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint,bottomConstraint])

}
```

although I wanted to know why your adding constraints to the button ,when you can declare  x and y at the time of initialisation. if you need help in that I've added the code for it too where the button is at center, hope it helps.

```
 lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button =  UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2-25, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2-25, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    return button
     }()
```